# Issue with unit identifier when using Fortran modules in C++

Tags: c++, fortran, interop

My main program is C++ and I need to use modules of an existing Fortran program. I was able to link to it with g++.
Problem is, all subroutines inside the fortran codes are designed to be called by a Fortran main program. Globally, the initialization of global variables in the latter is done by directing an input file on command line:

```
main_fortran_prog < inputFile.ext
```

A given subroutine "foubar" require these variables to be set. For that, It reads from unit identifier 5 which is, according to documentation I read, for INPUT from the keyboard with the READ statement.

Now, I want to call the subroutine "foubar" in my C++ main which will initialize theses variables "real_fou" and "bool_flag" before the subroutine operation. Knowing that "foubar" will look out the value of real_fou and bool_flag in namelist from unit identifier 5 which I'm trying to avoid, what are the best options for me?

In sum: *I want to migrate from a Fortran main to a C++ main. I'm trying avoid namelist reading from a file if possible*.

---

List of files in my directory:

**inputFile.ext**:

```
! this file is used by fortran main program to initialize global variable
&justANamelist
    real_fou = 0.3490834
    bool_flag = .true.
/
```

**afortmodule.f90**

```
module afortmodule
implicit none
integer :: ios
logical, save :: bool_flag
real, save :: real_fou

contains

subroutine foubar() bind(c, name='foubar')
    use iso_c_binding
    call parseInput
    write(*,*) "real_fou x 2 = " , real_fou * 2
end subroutine

subroutine parseInput
    ! Define the namelist
    NAMELIST /justANamelist/ real_fou, bool_flag
    ! How to bypass this in cpp call ?
    read(5,nml=justANamelist, IOSTAT=ios)
end subroutine

end module afortmodule
```

**main_fortran.f90**

```
! require < inputFile.ext
program mainfortranprog
use afortmodule
! call foubar to display real_fou x 2
call foubar
end program mainfortranprog
```

**main_cpp.cpp**

```
// This want to call the subroutine foubar in fortran module afort_module
// like main_fortran did but avoiding the commandline input like "<  inputFile.ext"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void call_foubar(void);
extern "C"{
    void foubar (void);
    bool bool_flag;
    double real_fou;
}

int main (void){
    real_fou = 3.13215163;
    bool_flag = true;

    //How can I use these values in namelist justANamelist 
    //in manner that I could be able to do:
    call_foubar();

    return 0;
}

void call_foubar(void){
    // some codes here
    foubar();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: from the look of the file i'm afraid the fortran is using namelist i/o .. (????) Please show the code!!

Comment: yes, it is. I don't have the authorization to share the full code but I will edit the question to provide more details adding relevant lines.

Comment: It is a **very bad** idea to rewind unit 5 even if the compiler does not immediately complain. Do not use unit 5 explicitly. It is not portable. Use unit `*` for standard input and output.

Comment: But I don't really get your problem. Please show the code. It is essential.

Comment: Do you just want to read the Fortran namelist to initialize values values in a C++ program?

Comment: Now I added files, I hope you can understand my problem now, please consider that I want to minimize modifications in the existing Fortran codes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have no choice but to read/parse the namelist in c++ and modify the fortran to take the values as arguments.

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you set `real_fou` to 3.14 before calling the subroutine? What do you want to happen when you call the subroutine?

Comment: I want the subroutine to use this value instead of the one in the input file. Is there a possibility to redirect a stream from C++ in replacement of inputFile.ext ?

Comment: @agentp: I'm thinking about too, but is there subroutine overriding in Fortran ? That would be great if It can have two forms depending on its arguments: if no argument, read from unit identifier 5; if not, use the given arguments.

Comment: Performing any sort of i/o in fortran called from c++ is going to be at least problematic. I'm pretty sure reading standard input is not possible. Fortran expects stdin to be pre-connected and it will not be under c++. There is no (non hacky) way to open it in fortran and no way to pass a c++ file object to a fortran i/o statement.  Are you trying to have one source callable from either c++ or fortran?

Comment: yes, that's what I want to do